# Access Denied Exception in AWS DAX

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I have created a DAX cluster and accessing it in a lambda function which runs in the same VPC. It shows the following response: *"Unable to get User Details: Error: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::4XXXXXXXX7:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForDAX/db-host-id-63XXX66 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:3XXXXXXX7:table/UserDetails"*.

The role 'AWSServiceRoleForDAX' was created **automatically** by AWS when I created the Dax cluster and **I can't edit it to add the permission - dynamodb:DescribeTable**. When I checked, the 'AWSServiceRoleForDAX' has the permissions for EC2. I am not using any EC2 instances. Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the lambda itself has permission to use dax and/or dynamodb?

Comment: Yes. I have attached a policy, in which I have added all the permissions for DynamoDB and DAX, to the execution role of Lambda